# Removing duplicate columns from an array with built-in functions

Tags: php, arrays, function

I need to remove some items from the following array based on the elements in the 0th position.

```
Big_array(256) {
  [0] => array(6) {
    [0] => string(4) "Data"
    [1] => string(15) "Ext_EBCS01_Cota"
    [2] => string(3) "CDI"
    [3] => string(3) "CDI"
    [4] => string(6) "IPCAdp"
    [5] => string(6) "IPCAdp"
  }
  [1]=> array(6) {
    [0] => string(10) "2014-05-05"
    [1] => int(100)
    [2] => int(100)
    [3] => int(100)
    [4] => int(100)
    [5] => int(100)
  }
  [2]=> array(6) {
    [0] => string(10) "2014-05-06"
    [1] => float(99.04321866850199)
    [2] => float(100.040705)
    [3] => float(100.040705)
    [4] => float(100.0218569233119)
    [5] => float(100.0218569233119)
  }
```

For instance, `Big_array` has some duplicated values on its 0th element, they are:

1. $Big_array[0][3]
2. $Big_array[0][5]

Based on the index of the duplicated elements I need to delete:

1. $Big_array[0][3]
2. $Big_array[1][3]
3. $Big_array[2][3]
4. $Big_array[0][5]
5. $Big_array[1][5]
6. $Big_array[2][5]

The remaining array should be re-indexed and have their keys in sequence like the following:

```
Big_array(256) {
  [0] => array(6) {
    [0] => string(4) "Data"
    [1] => string(15) "Ext_EBCS01_Cota"
    [2] => string(3) "CDI"
    [3] => string(6) "IPCAdp"
  }
  [1] => array(6) {
    [0] => string(10) "2014-05-05"
    [1] => int(100)
    [2] => int(100)
    [3] => int(100)
  }
  [2] => array(6) {
    [0] => string(10) "2014-05-06"
    [1] => float(99.04321866850199)
    [2] => float(100.040705)
    [3] => float(100.0218569233119)
```

Is there any built-in PHP function to do that?

Comment: [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) with [unset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built-in function to do it all in one pass, but you can do it with a combination of some array functions and a `foreach` loop:

```php
<?php
$repeatedIndexes = array_diff_key($Big_array[0], array_unique($Big_array[0]));

foreach($Big_array as &$value) {
    $value = array_values(array_diff_key($value, $repeatedIndexes));
}
unset($value);
```